# Какой элемент использовать WinForms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно отображать объекты задач в таком виде:
[image: Картинка]

Задачи имеют много свойств, хочу чтобы к примеру отображалось только название. При выделении задачи и нажатии на кнопке, я мог что то делать с объектами. Я не знаю какой элемент использовать для этого, пытался через ListView, там что то не понял. Я делал на WPF так, просто вроде бы добавлял контейнер, и там красиво все делал, здесь не знаю как. Можете подсказать пожалуйста

Comment: `FlowLayoutPanel` и `TableLayoutPanel` в помощь.

Comment: О, точно, панель же есть для такого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов. Ты можешь использовать `DataGridView`, условно в первой колонке будет задача, в следующей например какие нибудь действия с ними. В wpf я тоже использовал `listview`, он неплохо выглядит, и туду можно поместить контролы. У меня есть код с винформ (он не мой, просто копаюсь тут). Тут есть нечто похожее, создается `panel`, и в ней просто делают скрол и спавнят по координатам `тексблоки` и тп, но мне кажется это решение сомнительное, хотя на wf будет быстро работать. Лучший способ как по мне просто создать `grid` и класс задач, и через коллекцию добавлять и обновлять их, делал такое на avalonia (wpf подобное) если надо могу скинуть код. В общем можно через любой контейнер сделать и все.

Answer (score -1):

Для создания удобного интерфейса советую использовать **FlowLayoutPanel** и **TableLayoutPanel**

В этом видео более подробно показано о всех функциях и возможностях элементов.

[Использование FlowLayoutPanel и TableLayoutPanel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Oma-JnirU8)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)